# First recurring character in c++

Tags: c++

I've only found some answers to this problem in Python and JS, hopefully you can help me to do the same in c++.
So the challenge is to print out the first recurring character of a given string, here is what i came up with, but I don't know if this code actually looks good.  This is my first time posting on StackOverflow, hopefully I'll get some feedback =)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter some letters:\n";
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;

    // vector that stores characters that we will come across in the string
    std::vector<char> seen(0);

    for (char a : str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < seen.size(); i++) {
            if (a == seen[i]) {
                std::cout << a << std::endl;
                return 0;
            } else { continue; }
        }
        seen.push_back(a);
    }
    std::cout << "none\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"but I don't know if this code actually looks good."*. Do you want code review for style ? try https://codereview.stackexchange.com Do you want us to debug your code ? Not good place neither or provide some effort (problematic input, ...).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll check codereview.stackexchange.com out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For speed, how about:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter some letters:\n";
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;

    bool seen [256] = { };

    for (char a : str) {
        unsigned char u = (unsigned char) a;
        if (seen [u]) {
            std::cout << a << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        seen [u] = true;
    }
    std::cout << "none\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This is O(N), rather than O(N*N/2)

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rH5cbKK8eG3KCCzW)

Comment: So simple and so damn genius at the same time. No hash tables, no sets, just an array of booleans that's as big as the printable characters. great!

Answer (score 1):

For your task check out [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
void printRecurring(const std::string& str) {
  std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin(), e = str.end();

  for (std::string::const_iterator it2 = str.begin(); it2 != str.end(); ++it2) {
    it = std::find(it + 1, e, *it2);
    if (it != str.end()) {
        std::cout << *it2 << std::endl;
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it a little simpler by using std::find.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algoritm>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter some letters:\n";
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;

    // vector that stores characters that we will come across in the string
    std::vector<char> seen(0);


    for (char a : str) {
        auto it = std::find(seen.begin(), seen.end(), a);
        if (it != seen.end()) {
            std::cout << "Found it: " << *it << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        seen.push_back(a);

    }

std::cout << "none\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <algorithm>`